# Exception with svn authentication in hudson

Tags: svn, hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a job connected to svn repository, but recently it began to throw this exception and the build fails:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /job/logger/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote. Reason:

    hudson.plugins.zentimestamp.ZenTimestampNodeProperty cannot be cast to hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty

Caused by:

java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.plugins.zentimestamp.ZenTimestampNodeProperty cannot be cast to hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.getUrlWithoutRevision(SubversionSCM.java:2686)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRemote(SubversionSCM.java:2001)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:274)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:141)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:80)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:565)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:225)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:565)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:225)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:565)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:650)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:481)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1336)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:81)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:73)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I suspect that there is a compatibility problem with the versions of the hudson(3.2.1) and the subversion plugin(2.3.11). The credentials for the repository and the url of the project are correct.
Help is appreciated, because I don't any ideas what is causing the problem.

This is the os on which is running the server:

```
Linux hudson 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit: just saw ZenTimestamp Plugin and it's version is 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out a colleague has installed the ZenTimestampPlugin which converts the dates to timestamps and that was the source the problem. When I removed the conversion everything is working!